# How to read only the last line of a live input stream in a while read loop

Tags: shell-script, rsync, pipe, read, inotify

I have a very simple bash script that synchronizes data to a USB key as soon as new files appear. It is poorly written but it works, however I want to minimize CPU time so I used `sleep` but since I use inotifywait as a trigger for synchronization, the script adds one second of sleep for every new file added (and there are many small files). My solution would be that `read` only reads the latest line of inotifywait output, which I wanted to do by piping it into tail -1, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#!/bin/bash

watched_path=".wine/drive_c/Data"
rm -r "$HOME/$watched_path/"*
inotifywait -r -m "$HOME/$watched_path" --format "%e %w%f" -e create -e moved_to |
  while read action full_path; do
    sleep 1
    file=${full_path##*$watched_path}
    echo "'$file' appeared in directory '$watched_path' via '$action'"
    USB="USBKEY"

    # Wait for USB to be connected before syncing.
    until [ -e /media/$USER/$USB ]; do
      echo "Connect USB for sync."
      sleep 5
    done
    rsync -r "$HOME/$watched_path" /media/$USER/$USB
    echo "Sync complete."
  done
```

I sync the whole folder so it's okay if I miss a line of inotifywait, but I need it to be synced after the latest file (and thus latest line) at the moment of reading. This would mean that from the moment I stop sending files, the while loop will be executed at most one more time before hanging again.

How can I read **only the most recent line** of the inotifywait output?
If you have other suggestions avoiding this issue it's okay for me but I'm interested in the answer nonetheless.

Comment: How do you know it’s the last file?

Comment: from `man inotifywait`: `-m: Instead of exiting after receiving a single event, execute indefinitely. `

Comment: Well I'm assuming if I read the most recent line comming from inotifywait it's going to be the last file that was added.

Comment: Why couldn’t another file show up from the inotifywait output?

Comment: I'm sorry, I explained myself badly and chose my words badly, it's the latest file that I'm trying to get, but there can always be new files comming, (the script runs forever and a new batch of files can come at any time). I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: I, for one, am not understanding yet. The `-m` flag tells inotifywait to run *forever*, so there's either *never* a most recent line or there's *always* a most recent line. Are you wanting to batch the rsync commands together in some way, such that if 5 files are reported in quick succession (under X seconds), you'd only run one rsync?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the way `inotifywait` and pipes work. I imagine that it runs continuously filling up a buffer sent to the `read` command. `read` then reads this buffer line by line starting from the top until it reaches the bottom and hangs. I would like to read the bottom of the buffer (at the time of call to `read`) and discard the rest of the buffer because I am only interested by the trigger, not by the name of the file that appeared in the sync folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for a more complex scenario. You haven't described how to identify the "last" file to arrive, so this one simply times out after 5 seconds of file inactivity since at least one file has been transferred.

1. Set flag = waiting
2. In parallel: whenever a file is notified, set flag = not_done
3. Wait until flag == not_done
4. Start loop

   - Wait for USB to be connected and start the synchronisation process (`rsync`)
   - If any new files were transferred then set flag = not_done
   - Otherwise

     - If flag == probably_done then set flag = definitely_done otherwise set flag = probably_done
   - If we took less than five seconds then wait for the remaining time
5. Loop until flag == definitely_done

Since we need IPC between the main process and the parallel `inotifywait` process I'd consider implementing the flag as a file, possibly even a set of file names.

As far as I can tell [it's not easy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/467059/100397) to identify whether or not `rsync` has transferred new files. You might need to compare target directory contents before and after.